# Facebook Access Token - using the access token in PHP with JavaScript auth

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use the JavaScript authentication on my website but I want to get hold of the access token in PHP so that I can store the user's email address.
Is there a quick and easy way to this without using the PHP libraries?
Thanks!

PS - I know how to get the access token in JS:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
              if (response.session) {
                if (response.perms) {

                } else {
                  // user is logged in, but did not grant any permissions
                  alert("No Permission..");

                }
              } else {
                // user is not logged in
                alert("Please login to facebook");

              }
            }, {perms:'read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access'});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the PHP libraries: you just need to extract it from the facebook cookie. Previously answered at [Where to find the Facebook cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763197/where-to-find-the-facebook-cookie), which points at a quite nice writeup at http://publicvoidlife.blogspot.com/2011/01/quick-and-easy-facebook-integration.html

Comment: Thanks! $cookie['access_token'] is what I was looking for!

Comment: Glad to hear it was what you were looking for.